# How to save the instance in an edittext?

Tags: android, load, save, android-edittext

I'm creating an application for my school, and one activity in it is the notes-section. You'll be able to enter your notes, and when you leave the activity notes the app should save the instance (so the notes the user has put in), and when the activity is loaded again the instance should be loaded so that the user can view it and edit it. 
My code is:

```
    package me.menno.Ghlyceum;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Notes extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.notes);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    menu.add("Uitval");
    menu.add("Notities");
    menu.add("Help");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    String title = item.getTitle().toString();
    if (title.equals("Uitval")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (title.equals("Notities")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notes.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (title.equals("Help")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Help.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

    return true;

}
```

Could you please help me by saying where I should include the oncreate and saveinstance or something? I'm absolutely an beginner in Android, so if you could help me, would be great!

Thanks a lot,

Menno

Comment: if the note is sufficiently large, i.e. > 1KB or if you have multiple notes go with a local database using sqliteopenhelper. If its one small note, use shared preferences to persist.

Comment: Hi L7ColWinters,
I expect the file is small, because it's just text, not more than like 20 rules in most cases. Can you help me by including that code into my code?
Would be very nice!

Answer (score 0):

A good example can be found at http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial for creating an sqlite database with sqliteOpenHelper class. remember to use the application context for creating the helper object and not the activity context. i.e. getApplicationContext(). Also make sure to make your db instance static so that its persisted if an activity recreates itself. last but not least, sqlite3 is the name of sqlite on the android device. If your familiar with interfacing sql with the shell this is a helpful debug tool to manually see tables on the device and create/modify new ones.

Comment: I fixed it, without your help! Thanks for your time, but it isn't neccesary anymore ;)